# Is there a way to bind the datepicker textbox to a resx file & key and still maintain functionality as a datepicker?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I would like to have the datepicker display a different string in the textbox (not Select a date), and have the string stored in a resx file. I'm doing this because I'm frequently swapping between languages and I need the datepicker to be translated along with the rest of the app.

I have tried updating the controlTemplate of the datepicker, but I have been unable to incorporate the resx file into this.

```
<DatePicker Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="845,56,0,0" Name="dtpEndDate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" FontSize="16" Background="White" SelectedDateFormat="Short" TabIndex="30" RenderTransformOrigin="0.479,0.454">
                <DatePicker.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" Height="27"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DatePicker.Resources>
            </DatePicker>
```

Instead of the text being bound to Text, I'd like it to be connected to a resx file. I figured it would look something like

```
text = "{Resx ResxName=LegalServicesTimesheets.Labels, Key=DatepickerText}"
```

But this doesn't allow for the user to select a date, which is the whole point of a datepicker.

Comment: So you want to replace the default "Select a date" string with a custom one that is displayed only when there is no selected date, right?

Comment: its still the same answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712590/i-dont-want-message-select-date-in-datepicker look at @dba 's response to the question i linked you earlier

Comment: Exactly. When the app is first opened and before a date is picked, I want it to display something other than "Select a date", depending on what language is selected (something I'll take care of once the resx binding is working)

Comment: @DenisSchaf Of course! My bad, I hadn't clued in that this could be used for the resx. Thanks a bunch. The only problem is that this answer isn't in vb, but I think I can figure it out.

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just override the `ControlTemplate` of the `DatePickerTextBox` in your XAML markup:

```
<DatePicker Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="515,55.661,0,0" Name="dtpStartDate"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" FontSize="16" Background="White" 
                SelectedDateFormat="Short" TabIndex="20">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="custom...">
                                                <TextBlock.Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DatePicker}}" 
                                                                         Value="{x:Null}">
                                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </TextBlock.Style>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: The only problem is, when I end up choosing a date, the watermark stays and is overlaid by the date. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: @BrenCou: You could use a `Style` for the `TextBlock`. See my edit.